# Proof of Sylvester Gallai theorem using induction

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> A finite set $\mathfrak{S}$ of $n$ points in the Euclidean Plane has the property that any line through two of them passes through a third. Show that all the points lie on a line

Here's my proof using induction which I hope, is correct, though I somewhat believe there's a loophole in it.

So I was thinking if—

For $3$ points in the plane, it's obvious.
For $4$ points $A,B,C,D$, choose $A,B$. A line through $A,B$ implies that $C$ or $D$ is a part of it since if they don't belong to $AB$ (extended) then the statement isn't valid. So, WLOG $C$ belongs to $AB$ (extended). Now, $A—B—C$ (in some order). Join $C,D$ and $A,C$. You get a $\triangle$ which has to be degenerate for the statement to hold.

Now for the induction step, assume there are $k$ ($k\geq 3$) collinear points in the plane. For every other point in the plane that doesn't belong to the line, we can draw a $\triangle$ which has to be degenerate for the statement to hold.

Comment: What do you mean by "Join $C$, $D$ and $A$, $C$"?

Answer (score 0):

While the proof seems correct in essence, the triangle argument is slightly hand wavy as written. I would suggest you write it as follows:

Induction step: Consider points $P_1, P_2, ..., P_k$ for $k \geq 5$. By the induction hypothesis, the first $k-1$ points lie on the same line. However, since the induction hypothesis holds for any subset of these points, we can also state this for the last $k-1$ points. This means that points $P_2, P_3, ..., P_{k-1}$ all lie on the same line. Since $k-2 \geq 2$ there is only one such line, and therefore $P_1$ and $P_k$ also lie on that line.

Comment: I don't think this answer is right, I'm afraid! How do you know the induction hypothesis holds for any subset of the points? This fact is not obvious and is essentially the difficulty in proving this theorem.